# Mounted Disk Issue

Tags: 20.04, fstab, disk, automount, fdisk

Please go easy as I am somewhat a novice in Linux.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 and using it as a file server. I built it about a year ago and it has been working fine. This morning I rebooted the server for the first time in a while and it hung between checking the disks and maintenance mode. I was able to start in *Recovery Mode* and I noticed that one of my 6 hard drives was unmounted.

When I remove this drive's entry from `fstab`, the box boots fine and I am able to manually mount the drive. When I put it in `fstab`, I can only boot to *Recovery Mode* and remove the entry to get it to boot normally. When I manually mount the drive, I see no issues with performance, everything is there, and samba sharing (its intended use) works fine.

I don't know what I should do to troubleshoot and fix this issue. My normal course of action would be to replace the drive, but since it manually mounts, that seems unnecessary. Would be happy for advice on what to check.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/boot.log` that might explain the issue? 

Comment: [[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start [0;1;39mFile System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/7250f471-2656-4536-a39c-f6b930cd9fb1[0m.
See 'systemctl status "systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\\x2duuid-7250f471\\x2d2656\\x2d4536\\x2da39c\\x2df6b930cd9fb1.service"' for details.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39m/mnt/Data3[0m.

Comment: Is this troublesome disk part of a RAID set?  If so, then I'd like to see the output of lsblk -f

Comment: No RAID set up.  Its just one of six SATA drives.

Comment: if it matters, the lsblk -f shows it mounted normally now since I have manually mounted it.

Comment: Based on the log, you have either a storage failure or a power failure that is causing file inconsistencies. If it's a storage failure, this could be the sign of an impending disk failure. If it's a power issue, then you have too many devices drawing too much power at boot, causing an internal brown-out. One way to find out if it's a power issue is to disconnect one or more other drives and see if the failing disk starts up normally or not.

Comment: to check disk health you can check the disks smart values: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX` The important values are those in the colloms VALUE, WORST compared with THRESHOLD. smartctl is part of smartmontools package.